# "Show sympathy towards someone" or "toward someone", or both of them are not idiomatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, idioms, idiomatic-language

On this sites I find both of the usage:

https://ludwig.guru/s/sympathy+toward

https://ludwig.guru/s/sympathy+towards

What is the proper choice of preposition here after "sympathy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are common and natural.

According to this [Ngram view](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sympathy%20toward%20someone%2Csympathy%20towards%20someone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csympathy%20toward%20someone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csympathy%20towards%20someone%3B%2Cc0) on "sympathy towards someone" vs "sympathy toward someone", "towards" is more popular, which agrees with my own feelings.

Comment: I agree with your feelings. I also see that "sympathy for someone" is used 60x times more than "sympathy towards someone": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sympathy+for+someone%3B+sympathy+towards+someone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url= Are they the same meaning/usage or not?

Comment: @HighGPA Same meaning, and both are natural. Usually a 60x difference means the lower one is strongly dispreferred, but that's not my feeling. "Toward" is certainly more formal than "for", but I don't think that accounts for the difference.